# systemd: How to create runtime directories during package install?

Tags: systemd

When a package wants a runtime directory, there exists systemd's `tmpfiles.d` that may contain the temporary files a package needs.  So when installing an RPM package, it is the correct thing to install a *package*`.conf` file to `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/`, and then do a `systemctl daemon-reload`?

Obviously not: The newly required directories are not created. It seems one must explicitly run `systemctl start systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service`.  I'm confused: In pre-systemd area I simply added the runtime directory to the package, but now `/var/run` is empty after each boot.

What's the recommended clean solution for RPM and systemd?